# Elasticsearch derivate of a deep metric

Tags: elasticsearch, parent-child, aggregation

I have a web crawler that collects data and stores snapshots several times a day. My query has some aggregations that group the snapshots together per day and return the last snapshot of each day using `top_hits`.

The documents look like this:

```
"_source": {
  "taken_at": "2016-02-01T11:27:09.184-03:00",
  ... ,
  "my_metric": 113
}
```

I'd like to be able to calculate the derivative of a certain metric, say `my_metric`, *of the documents returned by* `top_hits` (i.e., the derivative of the last snapshots of each day's `my_metric`).

Here's what I have so far:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "filtered_snapshots": {
      "filter": {
        // ...
      },
      "aggs" : {
        "grouped_data": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "taken_at",
            "interval": "day",
            "format": "YYYY-MM-dd",
            "order": { "_key" : "asc" }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "resource_by_date": {
              "terms": { "field": "remote_id" },
              "aggs": {
                "latest_snapshots": {
                  "top_hits": { 
                    "sort": { "taken_at": { "order": "asc" }},
                    "size" : 1
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "my_metric_deriv": {
              "derivative": {
                "buckets_path": "resource_by_date>latest_snapshots>my_metric" 
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get a "No aggregation [my_metric] found for path ..." error with the query above.

Am I using a wrong bucket_path? I've read through the [bucket_path](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline.html#buckets-path-syntax) and the [derivative](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-derivative-aggregation.html) documentation and haven't found much that could help.

The documentation mentions briefly "[deep metrics](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_sorting_based_on_deep_metrics.html)", stating that they can be limited in some ways, which I couldn't quite understand. I'm not sure how or if the limitations affect my case.

Comment: In your `bucket_path`, `my_metric` refers to a field of your documents, which is not allowed. A bucket path can only contain a path made of aggregation and its sub-aggregations, down to a sub-aggregation field (like a sum, a maximum, etc), but you cannot access a field within documents returned by a `top_hits` aggregation.

Comment: Another thing, your `top_hits` sub-aggregation is named **latest_** snapshot, but you are taking the oldest one, i.e. the one with the oldest `taken_at` date. Is that intended?